# Make JS more efficient using a for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm very new to JS and jQuery. I've been looking all over and trying different techniques to make my code more efficient. Basically, I have a menu that advances people down the page. One section of my code identifies if a particular `DIV` has been scrolled to, then adds/removes some classes from a couple elements. Since I'm not sure how to dynamically grab anchor tags within a content area, I'm using the ID naming convention of `section-#`.

So, instead of repeating the same block of code with just a number changed, I was hoping a `for` loop would help make my JS more efficient, but I don't think I have it quite right.

**Original code:**

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        $("#jhscroller-menu li a").removeClass("active");
        $(".jhscroller-menu-prog-dot").removeClass("active");

        if (windowpos >= $("#section-1").offset().top) {
            $("#jhscroller-menu li a").removeClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-1"]').addClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-1"] .jhscroller-menu-prog-dot').addClass("active");
        }

        if (windowpos >= $("#section-2").offset().top) {
            $("#jhscroller-menu li a").removeClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-2"]').addClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-2"] .jhscroller-menu-prog-dot').addClass("active");
        }

        if (windowpos >= $("#section-3").offset().top) {
            $("#jhscroller-menu li a").removeClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-3"]').addClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-3"] .jhscroller-menu-prog-dot').addClass("active");
        }

        if (windowpos >= $("#section-4").offset().top) {
            $("#jhscroller-menu li a").removeClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-4"]').addClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-4"] .jhscroller-menu-prog-dot').addClass("active");
        }

        if (windowpos >= $("#section-5").offset().top) {
            $("#jhscroller-menu li a").removeClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-5"]').addClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-5"] .jhscroller-menu-prog-dot').addClass("active");
        }

        if (windowpos >= $("#section-6").offset().top) {
            $("#jhscroller-menu li a").removeClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-6"]').addClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-6"] .jhscroller-menu-prog-dot').addClass("active");
        }

        if (windowpos >= $("#section-7").offset().top) {
            $("#jhscroller-menu li a").removeClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-7"]').addClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-7"] .jhscroller-menu-prog-dot').addClass("active");
        }

        if (windowpos >= $("#section-8").offset().top) {
            $("#jhscroller-menu li a").removeClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-8"]').addClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-8"] .jhscroller-menu-prog-dot').addClass("active");
        }

        if (windowpos >= $("#section-9").offset().top) {
            $("#jhscroller-menu li a").removeClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-9"]').addClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-9"] .jhscroller-menu-prog-dot').addClass("active");
        }

        if (windowpos >= $("#section-10").offset().top) {
            $("#jhscroller-menu li a").removeClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-10"]').addClass("active");
            $('a[href$="#section-10"] .jhscroller-menu-prog-dot').addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

**New code:**

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        $("#jhscroller-menu li a").removeClass("active");
        $(".jhscroller-menu-prog-dot").removeClass("active");

        for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            if (windowpos >= $("#section-" + i).offset().top) {
                $("#jhscroller-menu li a").removeClass("active");
                $('a[href$="#section-"' + i + ']').addClass("active");
                $('a[href$="#section-' + i + '] .jhscroller-menu-prog-dot').addClass("active");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[Here's a CodePen of the working menu](https://codepen.io/alexhessrobinson/pen/KEobVb), to get an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: "I don't think I have it quite right": Please elaborate.

Comment: You misplaced some `"`. Here is what you should use: `'a[href$="#section-' + i + '"]` (twice inside the `for-if` construct). I will vote to close as 'Typographical error'.

Comment: Side note; I would highly suggest you cache some of the DOM lookups outside of the scroll handler, and use the cached results inside the event handler, even if you have to use filter() to get specific elements.  The more DOM lookups you have to perform in a scroll event listener, which scroll fires **a lot**, the less responsive it will be.

Comment: When I update my code to include the for-loop, instead of repeating the code blocks with just one number changed, it no longer works. So to elaborate, I'm trying to reduce the amount of lines of code by using a for-loop, but it doesn't seem to be working like I thought it would (doesn't work at all).

Comment: Thanks, @PeterB! That did the trick. I got lost inside my quotes.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#jhscroller-menu li a").removeClass("active");` - You are always removing the class in each iteration effectively undoing whatever you did in previous iterations.

You can avoid the fixed iteration count by doing (note I'm adding a CSS class because it makes more semantical sense than scanning for href): `<a class="content-link" href="#anything" />`

```
var $contentLinks=$('a.content-link');
for(var i=0; i<$contentLinks.length; i++){  // More efficient than .each()
    var $link=$($contentLinks[i]);
        $section=$($link.attr('href'));
    if($section.offset().top>windowpos){
        $link.addClass('active');
    }
}
```

Note, there is usually no need to add `.active` both to the anchor and contained dots, you can rewrite the css for the dots using the nested selector (`.active .jhscroller-menu-prog-dot {...}`). Also for this reason, the usual convention is to actually set all classes on the `<li>` so that the CSS/HTML is more scalable; just add it once on the topmost element that represents an item. This way, someone who is coming after you can restyle everything on and inside the `<li>` by just using CSS.